# Obtain distance knowing combined velocity of a bus and a taxi

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

A taxi and a bus go from town A to town B. This distance, a taxi does it for $4$ hours while the bus does it for $6$ hours.

Their velocity combined is $100$ km/h. Find the distance from A to B.

My calculation till now is that the taxi has a velocity of $60$ km/h while the bus has a velocity of $40$ km/h. Thus, the distance is $240$ km. I just want to check my results.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Should note:  it is easy to check the result once you have it, since $\frac {240}{40}=6$ and $\frac {240}{60}=4$.

Comment: What does "velocity combined" mean? If it means "sum of velocities," the given anwer is correct. If it means "average velocity" the answer is wrong. Inthat case 100x(4+6)=d(A,B+d(A,B). so d(A,B)=500. Whover set the question is incompetent. Questions should NOT be vague or ambiguous. Marking such questions and dealing with student appeals are nightmares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We wish to calculate the distance $x$ between $A$ and $B$ given the following information:

1. $\frac{x}{v_t} = 4$
2. $\frac{x}{v_b} = 6$
3. $v_t + v_b = 100$

Rearranging 3. and substituting into 2. we have $x = 6(100 - v_t)$.

Rearranging 1. and equating we have $4v_t = 600 - 6v_t \implies v_t = 60$ and substituting back into 1. gives us $x=240$.